# How to override notfound() in web.py for a REST API?

Tags: json, rest, python-2.7, web.py

I trying to understand how to deal with HTTP error codes using web.py as a REST framework. I can easily use try/catch blocks to return HTTP 404, 400, 500, etc... but I am having a hard time sending a custom JSON message with it.

```
import web
import json
urls = (
    '/test/(.*)', 'Test'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

def notfound():
    return web.notfound(json.dumps({'test': 'test'}))

class Test:
    def GET(self, id):
        web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        return self.get_resource(str(id))

    def get_resource(self, id):
        result = {}
        if id == '1':
            result = {'1': 'one'}
        elif id == '3':
            return web.notfound()
        return json.dumps(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.config.debug = False
    app.notfound = notfound
    app.run()
```

This works fine, but when `id == 3`, I cannot override the behaviour, and the `Content-Type` header is duplicated:

```
# curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/test/3
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 09 Sep 2013 23:59:28 GMT
Server: localhost

404 Not Found
```

How can I return a JSON Content-Type, with a custom message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Errors in web.py should be raised as exceptions.

I used this class to decorate json error (it has specific output format in my app, so you may adopt it to your needs):

```
class NotFoundError(web.HTTPError):
    '''`404 Not Found` error.'''

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    def __init__(self, note='Not Found', headers=None):
        status = '404 Not Found'
        message = json.dumps([{'note': note}])
        web.HTTPError.__init__(self, status, headers or self.headers,
                               unicode(message))
```

I have created a simple [json api with web.py](https://github.com/w0rm/todo) you may want to check, believe me it has some interesting ideas.